# Cadastrar duas models separadas em uma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

hoje venho com outra pergunta, mas sobre código.
Seguinte, estou fazendo um sistema para cadastrar alunos e cursos e uma tela para cadastrar classes onde parte do cadastro é selecionar alunos e cursos para cadastrar a classe. fiz o seguinte:

Aluno model:

```
class Aluno < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :curso
  belongs_to :class_rom
```

Curso model:

```
class Curso < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alunos
  belongs_to :class_roms
```

Classe model:

```
class ClassRom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alunos
  has_many :cursos
```

ai fiz um esquema no form de cadastro de classe onde aparece um select box para escolher o nome do aluno e o nome do curso:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :aluno_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:aluno_id, @alunos,
                                :id, :nome, :prompt => true) %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :curso_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:curso_id, @cursos,
                                :id, :nome, :prompt => true) %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

porem na hora de cadastrar da um erro dizendo 
method not found 'aluno'

se alguem souber o que posso fazer para arurmar, pois até agora não encontrei nada em lugar algum

Answer (score 2):

Como o relacionamento de cursos e alunos é do tipo `has_many`, você precisa usar o attributo `curso_ids` e `aluno_ids`, por tanto seu form ficaria assim:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :aluno_ids %><br>
  <%= f.select(:aluno_ids,
               @alunos.map { |aluno| [aluno.id, aluno.nome] },
               {},
               multiple: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :curso_id %><br>
  <%= f.select(:curso_ids,
               @cursos.map { |curso| [curso.id, curso.nome] },
               {},
               multiple: true %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```